# LINQ: group by a field that is a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Publication objects:

```
public class Publication 
{
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to group my publication objects by their authors using LINQ.
My solution uses a dictionary and looks like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Publication>>();

foreach (var publication in list)
{
    foreach(var author in publication.Authors)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(author))
        {
            dict[author].Add(publication);
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(author, new List<Publication> { publication });
        }
    }
}
```

However this seems ugly to me. There must be a simple and elegant one-liner for this problem, but I can't get it straight. I also tried to flatten the list with selectmany on Authors property and group them afterwards but it strips out only the author strings and the publication objects are gone.

Comment: your solution is best option. Nothing to do better with LINQ here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LINQ you can do like this:

```
var groupedByAuthor = list
    .SelectMany(publication => 
        publication.Authors.Select(author => new { author, publication }))
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.author, keyValue => keyValue.publication)
    .ToArray();
```

But this will be a little bit slower.

Comment: It shouldn't be too much slower than the native code, and I'd argue about the elegancy of it :)

Comment: @Rawling SelectMany creates big array, that is unnecessary. GroupBy goes thru this big array. So in case native code, there is no new big array, and there is no run on this array) So, I argue, this is much slower. Not several orders slower, but may be several times. What is about elegance - anonymous type is created here, this is point argument also

Comment: `SelectMany` doesn't create an array, it merely unwinds the two levels of collection in a way similar to the two `foreach` loops in the question. `GroupBy` doesn't have to do another loop through, because it gets the results one-by-one as `SelectMany` creates them.

Comment: @Rawling I think you are right. I don't understand that fully, but i'm correcting my answer. ty

Comment: @Rawling May I ask you to write this LINQ code down, but unwrapped in to methods/cycles ?

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy For info, it's called Deferred Execution. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example

Comment: @Default Yeah, thank you. I know about yielding, but i'm not sure I understand how they are executed in runtime form labmda-methods chain

Comment: you can always check the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,02f5d280493ce132) - you'll see that the returned value from SelectMany is in fact a nested for each that yields the result

Comment: @Default Actually dotnet has another implementation:     private static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
    {
      foreach (TSource source1 in source)
      {
        foreach (TResult result in selector(source1))
          yield return result;
      }
    }

Comment: Also I checked Grouping code. It makes Lookup.Create, that is actually makes second run. So I think it will be slower:     internal static Lookup<TKey, TElement> Create<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
      if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (source));
      if (keySelector == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (keySelector));

Comment: if (elementSelector == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (elementSelector));
      Lookup<TKey, TElement> lookup = new Lookup<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
      foreach (TSource source1 in source)
        lookup.GetGrouping(keySelector(source1), true).Add(elementSelector(source1));
      return lookup;
    }

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you are asking others to write down how it is implemented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167287/discussion-between-eugene-gorbovoy-and-default).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq and some anonymous classes:

```
public class Publication
{
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<Publication> publications; // YOUR DATA HERE!

        var groupsByAuthor = publications.SelectMany(publication => publication.Authors.Select(author => new { Publication = publication, Author = author })).GroupBy(x => x.Author);

        foreach (var gba in groupsByAuthor)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gba.Key);
            foreach (var pub in gba)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pub.Publication.Title);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile as-is. You should either make `publications` a field or assign it something

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Obviously you need data, I don't know where the OPs data comes from, he did not say...

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. I commented for future copy-pasters

Answer (score 0):

If you more concerned about clean  and expressive code you may want to try creating an extension method instead brute forcing an ugly linq query. Code should look something like the following.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Publication> test = new List<Publication>();
        Dictionary<string, List<Publication>> publicationsByAuther = test.GroupByAuthor();
    }
}


public static class Extensions
{

    public static Dictionary<string, List<Publication>> GroupByAuther(this List<Publication> publications)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<Publication>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Publication>>();
        foreach (var publication in publications)
        {
            foreach (var author in publication.Authors)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(author))
                {
                    dict[author].Add(publication);
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(author, new List<Publication>
                {
                    publication
                });
                }
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might think about separating the case of adding a new author from adding a publication. Turning the code into something like that:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Publication>>();
foreach (var publication in list)
{
    foreach (var author in publication.Authors)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(author))
            dict.Add(author, new List<Publication>());
        dict[author].Add(publication);
    }
}
```

It is not LINQ and not a new solution, but maybe it can help about the elegancy

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it like this :

```
var dict = pubs.SelectMany(p => p.Authors)
               .ToDictionary(
                   a => a, 
                   a => pubs.Where(p => p.Contains(a)).ToList())
               );
```

Not tested but you get the idea.

Comment: very very slow, one of the slowest way possible)